# UPDATED Displaying And, Choosing A Daily Double - Html / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[UPDATED VERSION] I am building a website that will need to have a person from an array be chosen each day, and displayed. But, for some reason it will only show the daily double when its the first time today. Here it is:

---

```
<DOCTYPE html!>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
    <div id="dd">
        <h1>Todays Daily Double Is: </h1><h1 id="person"></h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onload(argument) {
            document.getElementById('person').innerHTML = rand;
        }
        function runOncePerDay(){
          var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

          // if this function already ran today, do not continue.
          if( localStorage.yourapp_today == today ) return;

          // save today's date on the client's computer
          localStorage.yourapp_today = today;

          // your code below
            myArray = ["Ethan Goodhart", "Emma Meyers", "Toby Parker"];   
            var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
            document.getElementById('person').innerHTML = rand;

        }

        runOncePerDay(); // will work   
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `rand` in your `onload` is always undefined. Have a look into variable scopes... A `script` in a `div` is never good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to solve it won't work. Your `rand` variable won't magically remember what it was on that client's machine the last time they have opened the site. Instead, you should work with the last update timestamp and refresh localStorage only when it's needed, but you always have to get the data from localStorage in the first place. Below is a working implementation of what you want:

```js
function onload() {
  var data = localStorage.getItem("appSettings");
  if (! data || ! isTodayDate(JSON.parse(data).date)) {
    data = getData();
  }
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  document.getElementById("person").innerHTML = data.text;
}

function isTodayDate(date) {
  return moment().diff(moment(date), 'days') == 0;
}

function getData() {
  var myArray = ["Ethan Goodhart", "Emma Meyers", "Toby Parker"];   
  var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  var obj = {
    date: moment(),
    text: rand
  };
  localStorage.setItem("appSettings", JSON.stringify(obj));
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

onload();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<h1>Todays Daily Double Is: </h1><h1 id="person"></h1>
```